# Is it possible to do a loop and case in Pyspark?

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, case, apache-spark-sql

Is it possible to loop through some data in Pyspark and then based on a case statement come out with new values? (Since I've learned cases don't exist in Python).

For example: if my table is

DayofWeek

```
Monday
Tuesday
Monday
Wednesday
Monday
```

And my case statement is something like

```
Case
  When "DayOfWeek" is "Monday" then = 1
  When "DayOfWeek" is "Tuesday" then = 2
  When "DayofWeek" is "Wednesday" then =3
```

And the output would then be something like:

DayNumber

```
1
2
1
3
1
```

I'm guessing I need to do some sort of loop - loop through each one and in that step of the loop apply the current value to a case statement - but I'm lost at how to accomplish this. Case isn't possible in Python? Should I do just el if?
Should I use a case in SQL (Like when?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up getting it working - this is what I used in case anyone else is interested!

```
df = df.select('*',
          when(df.DayofWeek == 'Monday', 1)
          .when(df.DayofWeek == 'Tuesday', 2)
          .when(df.DayofWeek == 'Wednesday', 3)
          .otherwise(None).alias('DayNumber'))
```

I learned that I don't need to do a for loop and loop through each one, just doing that alone, will apply that logic for the conditions to every value.

That's what solved it for me! (and then you can show it to make sure it's right - that was just storing it (df.select(< whatever columns you want >).show() and it will spit out the table based on the columns you wanted to show in that dataframe).

Answer (score 0):

As of python3.7, this hasn't been implemented.
[Py docs, 4.1. if Statements](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements) reads,

> An if ... elif ... elif ... sequence is a substitute for the switch or case statements found in other languages.

An alternative method would be to use a dictionary function like this,

```
def dayNumber(day):
    return {
        "Monday": 1,
        "Tuesday": 2,
        "Wednesday": 3,
        # etc.
    }[day]
```